# Is it possible to buy Microsoft Word for Mac as standalone?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2008, microsoft-word-2008

I couldn't find a standalone Microsoft Word 2008 for Mac. I just need/want Word and nothing else.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to buy MS Word for Mac
>   as standalone

From Apple:

> http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/productivity_tools/microsoftoffice2008formac.html

Comment: That link doesn't work anymore.